# fft based polynomial multiplication with biginteger coefficients

Tags: python, fft, biginteger

I am trying to multiply two polynomial mod n ( n not necessairly a prime) with bigint coefficents I am trying to do that both with python and with boost::multiprecision library.

The problem I am facing is that when multiplying bigint with cos or sin the precision goes down so much that the result is not correct, and when I increase the accuracy using something like sympy or multiprecision float the multiplication becomes very slow. Using NTT has its own problems ( multiplying modular arithmetic modulo two numbers does not make sense in many cases).
So, the question is, is there a way to do what I want efficiently?

most of what I can find on FFT based polynomial multiplication does not address this issue

any paper or something else I would be willing to read and implement

This is my python code for fft

```
def fft( b,  invert=False) :
    a=[mp.mpc(0)]*len(b);
    a[0:len(b)]=b;
    n=len(a);
    if (n == 1):
        return a;
    a0=[mp.mpc(0)]*(n//2);
    a1=[mp.mpc(0)]*(n//2);
    for i in range(n//2) :
        a0[i] = mp.mpc(a[2*i]);
        a1[i] = mp.mpc(a[2*i+1]);
    a0=fft(a0, invert);
    a1=fft(a1, invert);
    factor=[-1,1];
    ang = (mp.mpf(2) * mp.pi / n) * factor[int(invert)];
    w=mp.mpc(1);
    wn=mp.exp(mp.mpc(real=0,imag=ang));
    
    for i in range(n//2) :
        a[i] = a0[i] + w * a1[i];
        a[i + n//2] = a0[i] - w * a1[i];
        if (invert) :
            a[i] /= mp.mpc(2);
            a[i + n//2] /= mp.mpc(2);
        w *= wn;

    
    ret
```

and my python code for polynomial multiplication

```
def polyMulFast(p1,p2,n):
    r=len(p1);
    m=2**(r.bit_length());
    p1F=[0]*m;
    p2F=[0]*m;
    p1F[0:len(p1)]=[mp.mpc(x) for x in p1];
    p2F[0:len(p1)]=[mp.mpc(x) for x in p2];
    p1F=fft(p1F);
    p2F=fft(p2F);
    result=[0]*m;
    for i in range(m):
        result[i]=p1F[i]*p2F[i];
    result=fft(result,True);
    res=[0]*r;
    for i in range(len(result)):
        res[i%r]+=int(round(result[i].real));
       # res[i%r]%=n;
    #res[i%len(p1)]%=n;
    return res;
```

it works well on polynomials with small coefficients,

but once the coefficients are big enough( around 500 bits) it does not work

Comment: In what way does it not work? Also, I don't think you can use complex or real numbers as primitive roots of unity in this kind of fft. See [number-theoretic transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform_over_a_ring#Number-theoretic_transform).

Comment: it does not work in the way that, when I compute the multiplication using FFT the coefficients are different from when I compute the multiplication using the regular way aka convolution). There are multiple papers that state that using FFT is possible in this scenario such as https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/primality_journal.pdf

Comment: Not to mention that it actually works when n is not a bigInt such as a 64 bit number or so, also when I increase the precision of the cos and sin functions using boost::multiprecision it also works, but then the gain from using FFT is removed by the time it takes to do the bigfloat arithmeatic.

NTT  does not really work in my case. Not sure why but my guess is that it is due to the fact that I am working on a ring modulo n where n is not necessairly a prime. Then using NTT there are two modulos taken and that does not necessarily work, and I don't know how to fix that